# Find first occurrence of string or return end of file

Tags: search, matlab

I am currently setting up my Vim to work with matlab. In matlab, sections are separated by `%%`, and I am looking for a command to select my current section.

I currently use

```
nnoremap <Leader>f mf:?%%<CR><Down>v/%%<CR><Up>$:SlimuxREPLSendSelection<CR>`f
```

to mark the current position as f, search upwards for %%, and select to the next occurrence of %%. The selection is then send to the matlab terminal via Slimux and then I go back to mark f.

However, I would like to extend this to the case when there is no %% before the cursor (then vim should go to the beginning of the file) or when there is no %% after the cursor (then vim should go to the end of the file).

Thank you.

**EDIT**

The solution by Tumbler41 almost worked for me, I had to change it a tiny bit because the Slimux function call wouldn't work and to make it able to cope when the cursor is on `%%`.

```
nnoremap <Leader>f :call SendSection()<CR>:SlimuxREPLSendSelection<CR>`f

function! SendSection()
   normal! mf
   if (search('%%', 'b') <= line("'f"))
      normal! jV
   else
      normal! ggV
   endif
   if (search('%%') > line("'f"))
      normal! k
   else
      normal! G
   endif
endfunction
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
nnoremap <Leader>f :call SendSection()<CR>

function! SendSection()
   normal! mf
   let firstLine = search('%%', 'b')
   if (firstLine != 0 && firstLine <= line("'f"))
      normal! jV
   else
      normal! ggV
   endif
   if (search('%%') > line("'f"))
      normal! k
   else
      normal! G
   endif
   '<,'>SlimuxREPLSendSelection
   normal! `f
endfunction
```

Note: I don't have Slimux and therefore can't test that part.

I'm using `search()` to find out if there is a `%%` before and after the mark `f`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I had to change the code a tiny bit and have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the [slimux](https://github.com/epeli/slimux) you can use `:SlimuxREPLSendLine` with a line range. `\%^` and `\%$` mark the start and end of the file respectively. Combine these regex anchors with a pattern alternation (`\|`), we can search for `%%` or one of the anchors.

```
nnoremap <leader>f mf:+?\(%%\n\zs\<bar>\%^\)?,-/\(\zs\n%%\<bar>\%$\)/SlimuxREPLSendLine<cr>`f
```

Note: Due to how trickiness of the range, this mapping will not work when you are on a `%%`.

To take this further you may want to may want to look into [vim-textobj-user](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-user). Here is a quick and dirty text objects:

```
xnoremap i% :<c-u>call search('\(%%\<bar>\%^\)\_s*\zs.', 'cbW')<cr>m<:call search('.\ze\_s*\(%%\<bar>\%$\)', 'We')<cr>m>gv
onoremap i% :normal vi%<cr>
```

Now you can use `i%` text object. Now we can pair it with the a new mapping which uses this text object:

```
nmap <leader>f mfvi%:SlimuxREPLSendSelection<cr>`m
```

For more help see:

```
:h :range
:h /\|
:h /\zs
:h /\%^
:h /\%$
:h search(
```

Comment: I'm not great with regular expressions, could you explain what `\n\zs\<bar>` does?

Comment: @FlorianW it matches after a line return. The `\zs` sets the start of the match after the new line. The `\<bar>` is an escaped version of `\|` for regex alternations or branches. Please see the help topics provided in the post.